# Service not get called in android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, background-service

I'm building a simple reminder application that will remind you of your events.

I've just used "Alarm Manager" with "Broadcast Receiver " to trigger my service at a certain time in the future. The purpose of the service is to vibrate the device when the notification arrives. Notification is working fine but, the Service isn't working as expected. I know that I can simply put the code for vibration inside the "Broadcast Receiver" but NEED TO KNOW ABOUT THE SERVICE. Don't know what's wrong with my code help me out guys, THANKS in advance.

Broadcast Receiver as follows:

```
public class NotificationSetter extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("AlarmTriggered", "Alarm is triggered to start background service");
            Intent serviceVibes = new Intent(context,BackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(serviceVibes);

            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //creating the Notification

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Notify");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.reminder);
            builder.setContentTitle("Reminding of your event");
            builder.setContentText("Time to play Cricket");
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManagerCompat compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            compat.notify(3000, builder.build());
    }

}
```

My service class:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("ServiceStarted", "Service is started using NotificationSetter");


        Vibrator vibes = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            vibes.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(2000,200));

        }else {
            vibes.vibrate(2000);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remindme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


    <application

        android:name="com.example.remindme.MyContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".StopAlarm"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".GetEvent" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.remindme.BackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationSetter"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>
        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to use foreground service in Android 8 and above

Comment: @AdarshYashvanth  But, I want the service  to run in the background even if the app is closed. is it possible with foreground service?

Comment: First start a foreground service. Then start a background service from that

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, since Android 8.0 afterwards, an app cannot start a foreground service unless in a few conditions:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Check if your service is triggered when you have your app in foreground, meaning that your app has a visible Activity to user. If it works in this condition, then it means your problem lies in background execution limits introduced in Android 8.0. So to make your service work, you can start it as a foreground service by calling this line of code:

```
 ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, new Intent(context, YourBackgroundService.class));
```

A foreground service needs a notification to be shown at status bar. You can either grab an instance of your alarm notification and use it as the foreground service notification or create a new notification.

Comment: by using foreground service, is it possible to trigger the service even if the app is removed from recent apps?

Comment: Definitely yes, as long as you have no problem with the notification in status bar.

Comment: I just read about the Foreground Service a few moments ago, NO bro, I can't continuously use a notification in the status bar. I'm just asking what's the problem with  my code. JUST NEED TO KNOW WHY IT ISN'T WORKING. If you have any idea regarding that please let me know brother. THANK YOU.

Comment: Added more details to my answer. Check it @TroubleMaker